# Text Recognition of sparse Text

Tags: python, ocr, python-tesseract

[Image example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRyGL.jpg)

Hello everyone, I am currently working on a text detection problem using pytesseract PSM-11 in order to detect the text as well as possible.

TLDR: What are great alternatives to detect sparse texts in images over multiple lines

Preprocessing steps include rotating the image so the lines are horizontal.
Enlarging the image using resize, since it has a fairly high resolution.
Binarize the image using OTSU.

I am fairly new to the field of OCR so I am wondering what I could do better. I have investigated a bit into the TrOCR model from Microsoft on hugging face, but I have not the means to gather more data or to have a higher resolution.
In pytesseract I tried to use the oem LSTMs but without much of a difference. Is there a no-brainer that I miss?

```
results = pytesseract.image_to_data(global_dict[i]["preprocessed_image"], config='--psm 11',
                                                output_type=pytesseract.Output.DICT)
```

My output for this image is:

```
[('1,', (65, 105, 156, 41)),
 ('DP,', (394, 105, 679, 41)),
 ('HR', (198, 158, 629, 16)),
 ('Svvv', (774, 156, 54, 27)),
 ('3.95', (383, 142, 45, 22)),
 ('2.05', (692, 140, 44, 22)),
 (',', (833, 180, 26, 67)),
 ('8', (201, 182, 142, 34)),
 ('5.64', (490, 176, 45, 38)),
 ('-', (803, 198, 20, 12)),
 ('alg', (68, 225, 59, 41)),
 ('S05', (192, 225, 146, 41)),
 ('SB', (504, 225, 226, 41)),
 ('IG', (882, 225, 194, 41)),
 ('3,05!', (220, 220, 53, 30)),
 ('24', (442, 229, 25, 22)),
 ('3,582', (587, 220, 54, 30)),
 ('2.19°', (906, 221, 51, 28)),
 ('24', (1080, 222, 24, 22)),
 ('Aer', (68, 222, 85, 93)),
 ('TS', (254, 291, 202, 8)),
 ('SOE', (611, 222, 280, 93)),
 ('kn', (71, 381, 136, 25)),
 ('a', (286, 381, 96, 25)),
 ('al', (73, 382, 760, 22)),
 ('4', (91, 375, 12, 21)),
 ('9', (105, 376, 10, 21)),
 ('1.01', (158, 373, 35, 23)),
 ('86', (255, 368, 24, 22)),
 ('1.01', (350, 367, 36, 21)),
 ('1,875', (493, 361, 52, 28)),
 ('18', (648, 366, 21, 21)),
 ('1.69', (700, 365, 41, 21)),
 ('18', (839, 364, 22, 22)),
 ('BR', (350, 429, 19, 20)),
 ('1.25', (383, 429, 35, 20))]
```

Another point, for me it is crucial to know the position of the located text, hence I use image_to_data.

I am not sure about the confidence levels, but sometimes pytesseract returns me multiple Characters that aren't even in the picture or nonsense like this  —————*—*—*$*$*$*$*$$$*$*$*$*$*$__$*$*$*$—*$*$*$—$*—*—$—$—$——_— (different picture).

Therefore I am wondering if there are some red flags I miss or if it is just pytesseract that can't perform.